# Concatenating files in Bash

Tags: bash, awk

Suppose I am writing a shell script `foo.bash` to concatenate the contents of `test/*.txt` with a comma like that:

```
> cat test/x.txt
a b c
> cat test/y.txt
1 2 3
> foo.bash test
a b c,
1 2 3
```

How would you write such a script ?

Comment: The example you give is inconsistent with your statement. Your files `test/x.txt` and `test/y.txt` are ending with a newline which is not available in the output.

Comment: Are your files having only single lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(in case you want to concatenate lines of files, line by line with comma).

```
 paste -d, *.txt
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** To concatenate all .txt files contents with `,` try following once(needed GNU `awk`).

```
awk 'ENDFILE{print ","} 1' *.txt | sed '$d'
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
for file in /tmp/test/*.txt; do
    echo -n "$(cat "$file"),"
done | sed 's/.$//'
```

or maybe

```
for file in /tmp/test/*.txt; do
    sed 's/$/,/' "$file"
done | sed 's/.$//'
```

Comment: `cat "$file"; printf ',';` You don't need command substitution in the body of the loop like you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to do achive it.The command below grabs the content of every file and appends it after the name of the file (`$ARGV`).

```
$ grep -ER '*'
a.txt:a
b.txt:b
c.txt:c
$ perl -pe 's/^(.*)\n$/$ARGV:\1,/;' * > file.txt
$ cat file.txt
a.txt:a,b.txt:b,c.txt:c,
```

Comment: This is not adding the content of the files.